# How to log in/log out from facebook integrated in android app?

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I implemented facebook login in my android app, and using signing in my app, but i do not know how to log out a user? after signin if i re-launch and re-signin i always see "You have already authorized AppName" and want to take the user data like email,name etc. My purpose of using facebook is authorize users to use app, take the user information,and logout. that's all.
This is how i am signing in.

```
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            System.out.println("Facebook Login Successful!");
            System.out.println("Logged in user Details : ");
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
            System.out.println("User ID  : " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId());
            System.out.println("Authentication Token : " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
            Toast.makeText(RegisterOrSignIn.this, "Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterOrSignIn.this, "Login cancelled by user!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println("Facebook Login failed!!");

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterOrSignIn.this, "Login unsuccessful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println("Facebook Login failed!!");
        }
    });
```

But it never shows any toast,(I copied this code from somewhere)
and this two chunks for log out:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Really Exit?")
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                    RegisterOrSignIn.super.onBackPressed();
                }
            }).create().show();
}
```

I tried this so far but not getting what i want.

```
@Override protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
   LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
}
```

Comment: your code is correct! If you want to show the user permissions the second time just remove your app from facebook settings -> app and you are good to go.btw logging out clears the session and tokens from the sdk and does not revokes the permission you have granted

Comment: ok i got it. but how can i avoid this, like if user already logged in i have to send him on next activity. and if user logs in first time also than send him to next activity.

Comment: 1) why would you take the user data and log them out?! this sounds fishy 2) logout will NOT revoke the permissions and hence the user technically still has the app installed.

Comment: so there is no any way to log out from facebook from the app?